# KeyErrors while reading Twitter json files in Python

Tags: python, json, twitter, pandas, keyerror

I am trying to analyze a json file with data I have collected from twitter, but when I try to search for a keyword it says it is not found, but I can see it is there.  I tried this two different ways.  I'll post them below.  Any advice would be great.

**Attempt #1**:

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
import pandas as pan

tweets_file = open('twitter_data.txt', "r")
for line in tweets_file:
     try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            tweets_data.append(tweet)
     except:
            continue
tweets = pan.DataFrame()
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
```

**Attempt #2**: Same previous steps, but did a loop instead

```
t=tweets[0]
tweet_text = [t['text'] for t in tweets]
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
KeyError: 'text'
```

If I print `tweets_data`, this I is what I see. 'text',etc, is definitely, there.  Am I missing a character?

```
>>> print(tweet_data[0])   
    {u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'RT
    @iHippieVibes: \u2b50\ufe0fFAV For This Lace Cardigan \n\nUSE Discount
    code for 10% off: SOLO\n\nFree Shipping\n\nhttp://t.co/d8kiIt3J5f
    http://t.c\u2026', u'in_reply_to_status....
```

(pasted only part of the output)

Thanks! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not *all* your tweets have a `'text'` key. Filter those out or use `dict.get()` to return a default:

```
tweet_text = [t['text'] for t in tweets if 'text' in t]
```

or

```
tweet_text = [t.get('text', '') for t in tweets]
```

Comment: Thanks, Martjin!  I'll try they dict.get() function